# streaming machine learning pipeline with apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm using Beam to build a streaming ML pipeline that's very similar to Zeitgeist system mentioned in the original [MillWheel paper](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/41378.pdf). However, I'm have difficulty in using trained models to do online predictions (the blue vertical arrow "Models" in Figure 1. of the paper).

It seems that Zeitgeist models are updated incrementally each time (?) when a new windowed counter comes in. However, the specific model I'm using doesn't support incremental/online training, so I need to use some trigger/windowing to train the model in batches.

During prediction, I don't know how to align windows of features and batch-trained models.

- using side input (see below) can make the pipeline run, but it stucks at the prediction step waiting for the model to be materialized.
- `CoGroupByKey` does not work because the windows of `features` and `ensembledModels` are not the same.

I also want to do model ensemble, which makes things even more complicated.

Here's a rough sketch of what I have

```java
// Correspond to "Window Counter" in MillWheel paper
final PCollection<Feature> features = pipeline
            .apply(PubsubIO.read(...))
            .apply(...some windowing...)
            .apply(ParDo.of(new FeatureExtractor()));

// Correspond to "Model Calculator" in MillWheel paper
final PCollection<Iterable<Model>> ensembledModels = features
            .apply(...some windowing and data triggers...)
            .apply(new ModelTrainer()));

// Correspond to "Spike/Dip Detector" in MillWheel paper
// The pipeline stucks at here when run
final PCollection<Score> score = features
            .apply(ParDo.of(new Predictor()).withSideInput(ensembledModels));
```

Comment: This feels a bit broad. Could you focus on a single question at a time, and be clear about what you have tried?

Comment: @jdv - I edited the question. Do you think it's better now?

Comment: Would be interested in seeing *any* example of ML pipeline running on Beam, especially with an example of how it can scale up processing just by adding nodes to the Beam cluster.

Comment: @user1712447 There are some examples like [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/dataflow-prediction-example) that evaluates pre-trained models. However, I haven't found any examples of online training and prediction.

Comment: Thank you, interesting. Half of the equation, but interesting. Also this is the more sensitive aspect in production, potentially requiring autoscaling etc. I suppose I can take inspiration from that also to distribute the preprocessing of data before prediction comes into play. I'll take a look at the example, but if you have some pointers on how to use Beam to do that data preprocessing (no ML), that'd be very welcome as well (I'll continue digging, but if you know of anything already :-)).